# OSX - How to add $PATH to Xampp PHP

Tags: php, macos, unix, path, xampp

In my PHP file, I ran `var_dump(exec('echo $PATH'));` and got `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
Then I ran `echo $PATH`in terminal, I got `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

How can't I add $PATH variable to Xampp?

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump(exec('whoami'));`?

Comment: I got "daemon" from this

Answer (score 0):

Your `$PATH` represents folders that the system is already aware of, and can access the contents directly. That is all it does. This is a system level thing, not a PHP thing, but anything in your `$PATH` is already available to PHP.

You should be aware that Mac OSX and Linux both run on a UNIX command line, and it works exactly the same on both.

Say for example I have a directory like:

```
/usr/local/foobar
```

I want to use `foobar` for something. If it is not in my `$PATH`, then I have to access it with

`/usr/local/foobar`

If it is in my `$PATH`, then I can access it with

`foobar`

The `$PATH` is separated by `:` so if my `$PATH` is `/usr/local:/usr/bin`, then I have two folders that are known to the system automatically, being:

- /usr/local
- /usr/bin

And anything in those can be directly accessed.

If I want a list of them in PHP, I would use the following to get a list of the folders:

```
$path = explode(':', `echo $PATH`);
```

---

On the command line, you just do `echo $PATH`

If you need to add a new folder to it, you would do (from the command line) either:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/path/to/new/folder
```

or

```
export $PATH=/path/to/new/folder:$PATH
```

I would use the first one if I want the new folder to be at the end of the results, which would be the case if I were overriding an existing value in it with something else I want it to use instead. I would use the second option if I want my new folder to be put at the beginning of the list.

**DO NOT FORGET TO PREFIX OR SUFFIX THE NEW VALUE WITH `$PATH`, OR YOU WILL LOSE EVERYTHING YOU ALREADY HAD AND PROBABLY BORK YOUR SYSTEM**

If you add stuff to the `$PATH`, you also need to source your `.bashrc` file to tell the system to reload the path and be aware of the changes, like this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

**The reason your path is different**, is because from the command line, you are seeing the `$PATH` for *your user*, and from the script, you are seeing the `$PATH` available to *the user the webserver is running under*. To resolve this, you have two options:

- Run the webserver as your user *(which is a bad idea for security reasons, so I'm not going to bother explaining how to do this)*
- Edit the .bashrc for the user that the webserver runs under *(which is a better option)*

First, in your script, you want to do

```
echo `whoami`;
```

This will tell you what user the webserver is running under.

You can then use `sudo su webservername` (use the value you got from the above command in place of `webservername`), then use the above `export $PATH=...` and `source ~/.bashrc` to fix the path of the webserver account as needed, then `exit` to go back to your own account, or just close the shell window. Then go back to your script and do

```
var_dump( explode(':', `echo $PATH`) );
```

and you should see the correct values (in addition to whatever other folders the webserver had that you do not on your own `$PATH`).

You can also use vim or vi to accomplish this, by doing

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

and put one folder per line in that file, then save and close, and do `source ~/.bashrc` as you normally would to reload it. If you are not familiar with vim, use the `export` approach instead.